# What's the best practice to code shared enums between classes

Tags: c#, enums

```
namespace Foo
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        High, Low
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`MyEnum` is declared outside  `Class1`
cause I need it here and in other classes

Seems good, but what if I decide later to delete the file containing`Class1`?

`MyEnum` declaration will be lost!!

What's the best practice to code shared enums between classes?

Comment: You mean if you delete the file containing `Class1`? Just put `MyEnum` in its own file.

Comment: If you decide to delete Class1, your enum will still be there! Deleting the class and deleting the file the class is in are two different things.

Comment: I meant the file containing Class1 :)

Comment: Even if you put them in the same file at first, you can always move MyEnum to another file and delete the original file later.  Or even just remove Class1 from the file and rename the file.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The best practice is creating separate file for each class, enum, or other type.

MyEnum.cs

```
namespace Foo
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        High, 
        Low
    }
}
```

Class1.cs

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> What's the best practice to code shared enums between classes?

Have your enumerations each in a file of its own, with the same name as the enumeration.

```
// Foo\MyEnum.cs
namespace Foo
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        High, Low
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience it is also good to add explicit values to fields in case you store them in database as integers, because changing the order or adding/deleting value in between may end up in runtime fail:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        High = 1, 
        Low = 2
    }
}
```

Also notice I start from 1 to be aware that uninitialized variable is not treated as correct enum value. Another idea is to add None = 0 value.